# How can I create a table header that contains a column with buttons in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular and I have a table with some data. The first column is a checkbox for select/select all. Then the data columns follow. The data column is for update/delete. In the table header, I would like to add a couple of buttons (add row/delete selected).

[image]

I have the following code:

```
<button class="button-add-row"
        style="width: 20px!important; min-width: unset!important;"
        mat-button (click)="addUser()">
    <fa-icon [icon]="'file'"></fa-icon>
</button>
<button class="button-remove-rows"
        style="width: 20px!important; min-width: unset!important;"
        mat-button (click)="deleteSelectedUsers()">
    <fa-icon [icon]="'trash-can'"></fa-icon>
</button>
<button class="button-reload-rows"
        style="width: 20px!important; min-width: unset!important;"
        mat-button (click)="reloadUsers()">
    <fa-icon [icon]="'arrows-rotate'"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

Is there a way to add these buttons in the last table header column, instead of having them in a separate `<div/>` above the table? I would like to make things a bit more compact and easy on the eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nueukg?file=src/app/app.component.html)?

If you use a normal table its very easy. Add this things inside the `<tr><th>` part.

```
<table id="customers" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Person 1</th>
    <th>Person 2</th>
    <th>
      <div class="button-div">
        <div class="button">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            class="w-6 h-6"
          >
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              d="M20.25 7.5l-.625 10.632a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.247 2.118H6.622a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.247-2.118L3.75 7.5m6 4.125l2.25 2.25m0 0l2.25 2.25M12 13.875l2.25-2.25M12 13.875l-2.25 2.25M3.375 7.5h17.25c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125v-1.5c0-.621-.504-1.125-1.125-1.125H3.375c-.621 0-1.125.504-1.125 1.125v1.5c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125z"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            class="w-6 h-6"
          >
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              d="M11.25 9l-3 3m0 0l3 3m-3-3h7.5M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Emil</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use `button` instead of `div`. And yes, you can use the `fa-icon` instead of the `svg`'s, too.